# Extending django-registration fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to extend the fields in django-reg (with First name, last name and contact number). To this end, I have written an app (name=regfields), with the following contents: 
        http://dpaste.com/596163/

When I run syncdb, I see all the extra fields I have set up on the database, but, when I try and create an account, the extra fields I have given are not stored in my database.

What could be wrong?

Sorry, I am a django 101 user!

Comment: The indentation of the save() function in `newforms.py` looks off. Assuming that is not an error introduced by copying it into dpaste, that method is not a part of `RegistrationFormZ`.

Comment: Thanks Martley, you were absolutely correct. Many thanks!

Comment: I rewrote it as an answer. Please feel free to accept it.

Comment: The dpaste is now gone, and therefore this question is now much less useful. Code should be copied into the question directly.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is now gutted, because the dpaste its code exists in is now dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indentation of the `save()` function in `newforms.py` looks off. Assuming that is not an error introduced by copying it into dpaste, that method is not a part of `RegistrationFormZ`.